# Is there a way to prevent an IWorkbenchWindow from closing?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

So I have my `IWorkbenchWiondow` object, `window`. 
I add this listener to it:

```
window.addPageListener(new IPageListener()
{
    @Override
    public void pageOpened(IWorkbenchPage page)
    {
        // method stub
    }

    /**
     * Whenever the user tries to close the workbench window, this method gets called.
     */
    @Override
    public void pageClosed(IWorkbenchPage page)
    {
        if (MessageDialog.openQuestion(page.getWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), "Question", "Do you really want to close the application?"))
        {
            // YES, then no problem, close
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // NO
            System.out.println("Now what?");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void pageActivated(IWorkbenchPage page)
    {
        // method stub
    }
});
```

How can I stop the `window` from closing if the user says `No`? 
Or how can I achieve the same end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I've only given this technique a minimal test and it appears to work as expected.

From the `IWorkBenchWindow` get an IWorkbench object.

Add an `IWorkbenchListener` to the workbench object.

The listener has a [`preShutdown`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchListener.html#preShutdown(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench,%20boolean)) method that should allow you to veto the close.

Answer (score 2):

As @david said, the `IWorkbenchListener` has a `preShutDown` event that allows to veto the shutdown of the entire workbench by returning `false`.

The workbench is shut down when the last workbench window is closed or through actions such as *File > Exit*.

If you would like to prevent a single `IWorkbenchWindow` from being closed, you need to add a *close* listener to the shell that represents the workbench window.

For example:

```java
Shell shell = window.getShell();
shell.addListener( SWT.Close, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox( parentShell, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.YES | SWT.NO );
    messageBox.setText( "Confirmation" );
    messageBox.setMessage( "Close the window?" );
    event.doit = messageBox.open() == SWT.YES;
  }
} );
```

Setting the `doit` flag to false will prevent the shell from being closed/disposed.